# Подсчёт длительности MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Существует таблица, в которую добавляются дата начала и дата конца, а также длительность. Необходимо сделать, чтобы при добавлении длительность вычислялась сама путём вычитания даты конца от даты начала. функцию DATEDIFF() использовать при добавлении данных, насколько я понял, нельзя (как минимум, у меня это не сработало). Самое простое — создать триггер, но это решение кажется слишком топорным. Нет ли более изящного решения?
Нерабочий код моей попытки создания таблицы (обратите внимание на duration):

```
CREATE TABLE tours(
tour_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
departure VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
destination VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
departure_date DATE NOT NULL,
return_date DATE NOT NULL,
transport_type CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
duration DATE DATEDIFF(departure_date, return_date) NOT NULL,
price INT(7) NOT NULL,
tours_amount TINYINT NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с [MySQL 5.7.6 можно использовать "Generated Columns"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

Пример:

```
CREATE TABLE triangle (
  sidea DOUBLE,
  sideb DOUBLE,
  sidec DOUBLE AS (SQRT(sidea * sidea + sideb * sideb))
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, милсдарь. Рабочий вариант для потомков:

 duration DATE AS (DATEDIFF(return_date, departure_date)),

Comment: @emptybottle, всегда рад помочь :)